# Chat is down, status blog contains no info, why?

Tags: support, chat

[image]

When will the chat be back, and why is it down at the moment?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the fact that one of these questions gets asked every. single. time.

Comment: Given the fact that StackStatus.net never has updates for these minor updates, or major outages until after the fact, I have asked [that the tweets get added to the blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232079/can-statusstatus-tweets-be-posted-to-stackstatus-net-automatically)

Comment: @Won't. It's still a valid question to ask why StackStatus.net has no information.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen: 1) didn't say this question isn't valid 2) this question is not asking why SS.net has no information, it's asking why the site was down.

Answer (score 7):

Per the StackStatus [twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/469554744386531328)

> We are preparing to move #stackexchange and #stackoverflow chat services to Oregon, there will be a maintenance page for a few minutes.

It should be back up soon.

Edit: It's back up now.