# Can @StackStatus tweets be posted to StackStatus.net automatically?

Tags: feature-request, maintenance, outage, stackstatus

While it sounds crazy, some of us do not actually have twitter accounts and really do not use twitter at all, so we don't see tweets from [`@StackStatus`](https://twitter.com/stackstatus).  This is especially true for users behind corporate firewalls where Twitter access is blocked.

So when there are access issues, the first stop for many users is [StackStatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/), but it seems that updates there much less frequent than tweets, especially during an outage, and usually only after the fact.  Additionally, only major planned events are ever announced in advance there.  Minor outages, such as the recent [chat migration](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/469554744386531328) were never even mentioned, so unless someone was following @StackStatus on twitter (which would require an account), or thinks to check twitter feed, they won't be up to date on any on-going issues.

I realize updating a blog while in the middle of an outage or to announce a minor (and temporary) outage due to maintenance is not a productive use of time, so can StackStatus.net display the twitter feed, or even better, can tweets from @StackStatus automatically be added to the blog?  It would save many users from having to check 2 places every time they have an access issue.

---

<sub>Note there is similar sounding but essentially different suggestion: [Add Twitter status to StackOverflow maintenance page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225015/add-twitter-status-to-stackoverflow-maintenance-page) - about attaching the twitter feed to the maintenance page for Stack Exchange sites. This request is different in that it is about posting twitter feed posts to the Stack Status blog.</sub>

Comment: You don't need an account to view their tweets, you can view the entire timeline at https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Comment: @jonsca I realize that (I actually linked the twitter feed in my question), but if you don't participate in twitter, then your first instinct is not to go to that page.

Comment: At least they could ram the twitter feed into the sidebar...

Comment: A Twitter page is no different than any other page on the internet and the updates are real-time rather than having to wait for someone to manually post to a blog.  I think StackStatus.net is redundant, if anything.

Comment: @jonsca then they should stop using stackstatus.net.  Either it gets updated more frequently or they don't use it.

Comment: Gee, and it's super easy to add a Twitter widget on any page...

Comment: Voting to reopen. The other suggestion is about attaching the twitter feed to the maintenance page for Stack Exchange sites. This one is about posting twitter feed posts to the Stack Status blog. They aren't the same.

Comment: Actually, I completely misread that question and thought it was suggesting something closer to what I suggested.  Voting to reopen as well.  Thanks for the edit @gnat

Comment: Some of us can't actually access twitter at all, so adding a sidebar would be a non-starter -- corporate firewalls prevent it.

Comment: Doesn't Tweeter has an API? Shouldn't it be possible to always show the last 5 tweets very simply?

Comment: Since the changes to the StackStatus website last year (as described in [Improvements to site status and incident communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378941/335251)), stackstatus.net will generally be updated more regularly than the [@StackStatus Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackStatus). As such, is this feature request still applicable? (Or should it be closed as "No longer reproducible"?)

Answer (score 7):

> While it sounds crazy, some of us do not actually have twitter accounts and really do not use twitter at all, so we don't see tweets from @StackStatus.

I contest the premise here. I don't really use twitter either, and I have a twitter account, but I only check my feed once in a blue moon.

When the site's not working, I first visit StackStatus. I expect it to have major announcements on there, or major summaries of events.

**If it doesn't have anything there,** I then proceed to take a look at the @StackStatus twitter, which is handily linked in the sidebar of the StackStatus site:

[image: the stackstatus link at the bottom of the right hand side menu]

The fact I barely use twitter doesn't stop me checking it, nor should it stop anyone.

So, this statement from comments is accurate:

> if you don't participate in twitter, then your first instinct is not to go to that page

... but my second instinct is then to go to the Twitter page, and it should be for you too.

I'm fine with the StackStatus site not reposting twitter comments. I don't expect to see the same content in both: StackStatus moves slower and contains more major stuff, the twitter feed is fast-paced and contains close-to-immediate updates.

I'll also be fine if the StackStatus site *does* repost twitter comments. That'll be fine. I don't have any objection to this suggestion. But I do contest its premise that people who don't use twitter ought to have some reason to never visit the twitter feed.

Comment: I understand your point here.  I'm not necessarily rejecting the twitter feed.  I'm basically trying to save a step.  If the site maintenance page tells you to check stackstatus.net, then the updates should be there.  I just dislike the idea that we make users hunt for information about outages.  If the maintenance page linked to twitter rather than stackstatus.net, I'd be ok with it.

Comment: It actually feels like a "link-only answer" as it is designed now.  You force people to keep following links in pages to finally get to the answer (granted, it is only 2 links, but it is still 1 more than I think should be necessary)

Comment: Can't agree with following links or having a sidebar/iframe that loads twitter -- I do not have the ability to access twitter at work: social media sites are blocked by the corporate firewall.