# Date of twitter update at stackstatus

Tags: feature-request, twitter, stackstatus

As mentioned in the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232100/147650) stackstatus.net displays the last @StackStatus tweet.

It would be really useful to include the date of that tweet on stackstatus.net so we don't have to follow the link to Twitter only to determine it was from 4 days ago.

Comment: Since the changes to the StackStatus website last year (as described in [Improvements to site status and incident communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378941/335251)), I believe the site no longer displays the latest tweet from the [@StackStatus Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackStatus). Given that fact, I'm closing this question as "No longer reproducible". (Feel free to edit/reopen if the feature request is still applicable as is; otherwise, if you want to suggest a different change to the current system, post it as a new question instead.)