# Can't login to SEDE

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, data-explorer

When I try to login to SEDE, clicking any of the providers fails with "No OpenID endpoint found":

[image]

Comment: This has been disturbing me all morning.

Comment: What's disturbing, @bluefeet ... is that there's still an AOL option :(

Comment: Old school in the house @rolfl

Comment: See [Site currently down message at irregular intervals throughout today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249670), *At this point, the websites are up and running, but some services are still spotty (in particular the OpenId provider).*