# Can't explore Stack Exchange Data Explorer (errors trying to build new query and execute existing query)

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Both of the below errors are most likely related to the internal network issues that were reported in [StackStatus twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackStatus), but still think it's better reporting here.

1. When trying to [write a new query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), I'm greeted with the generic ASP.NET error page:

   > [image]
2. When trying to execute existing query ([example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile)) I get the error:

   > The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context.

Comment: Bug? Heck, that's just sentient servers knowing who you are and cringing.

Comment: Probably fall-out from the downtime this morning. As [Oded states](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249670/site-currently-down-message-at-irregular-intervals-throughout-today): *At this point, the websites are up and running, but some services are still spotty*

Comment: @Tim eh, this might be true! ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup, I clearly mentioned this in the very beginning of the post. Still, they might forget about those services so this can be used to remind them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: yeah, you are quite right. It wouldn't be the first time SEDE was left behind (or left disconnected after a database server move..).

Comment: SRE team has been informed and have reproduced the issue(s).

Comment: Hmm, we should probably have a better error page huh?

Comment: @Oded [this SRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_and_Relationships_Education) team? ;-)

Comment: @Tim this, or add a read only mode too. If you add error page don't forget the lolcat! :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you are on meta here, not in the Den...keep it civil please ;)

Comment: Oh, and it must be fixed now, Closey did fetch the latest tag in the Close vote room...

Comment: @rene yup, working again! Will post self answer soon if no dev would post first.

Comment: Umm.. Several seconds ago I still get this error page when browsing through SEDE. The last time I used SEDE was eight hours ago and it was working normally :(

Comment: @masegaloeh weird indeed!

Comment: Thanks for fixing @Marc, what happened there?

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249782/23354