# SEDE error when trying to run query

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I tried running some queries just now, but get this error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

tried both http and https, but same error. Not trying to log-in to anything even, just run a query.

Also I get runtime error after clicking on "Compose Query".

Comment: I tried to repro, but I'm not even getting that. I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error, with standard the "how to turn custom errors on" instructions.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249675/cant-explore-stack-exchange-data-explorer-errors-trying-to-build-new-query-and

Comment: I can log in, but I'm getting the error Matt mentions ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9CazU.png)) when navigating to `/stackoverflow/query/new` as both an anonymous user and when logged in.

Comment: I'm hitting this too. On some queries only... for example I can't run [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/25355/have-we-met), but I can run [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75438/whats-my-pundit-badge-progress).

Comment: they are working on it: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3068634#3068634

Comment: Can you give it a try now? It was stuck in an especially bad state after an internal issue we had exhausting UDP ports which hosed DNS and caused a great disruption in the force.

Comment: Yep, works here as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apologies this was still erroring out - the SQL auth used here was stuck in a very bad state after an internal DNS failure earlier.

We've kicked it with (likely excessive) force but it did resolve the issue.

Comment: If you can fix it, break it! Always work. :D